# MySQL CASE with COUNT query and adding another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a column (CLIENT) to my following MySQL query:

My table

```
CLIENT  SEVERITYLEVEL TOTAL
  Bob        4        27
  Bob        3        24
  Bob        7        19
  Bob        5        10
  Bob        8        9
  Bob        6        7
  Bob        1        5
  Bob        2        3
  Gin        2        6
  Gin        3        7
```

My Desired Output

```
CLIENT SEVERITYLEVEL  Total

Bob    Severe         63
Bob    Moderate       32
Bob    Critical       9
```

...

```
select 
(case when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 1) then 'Moderate' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 2) then 'Moderate' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 3) then 'Moderate' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 4) then 'Severe' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 5) then 'Severe' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 6) then 'Severe' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 7) then 'Severe' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 8) then 'Critical' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 9) then 'Critical' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 10) then 'Critical' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 10) then 'Critical' end) 
 AS `SEVERITYLEVEL`,count(0) AS `total` 

 from `s2` 
 group by (case when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 1) then 'Moderate' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 2) then 'Moderate' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 3) then 'Moderate' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 4) then 'Severe' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 5) then 'Severe' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 6) then 'Severe' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 7) then 'Severe' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 8) then 'Critical' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 9) then 'Critical' 
 when (`s2`.`SEVERITYLEVEL` = 10) then 'Critical' end) 
 order by count(0) desc limit 10
```

I got the table working correctly for the 2nd/3rd column (SEVERITY LEVEL+TOTAL)
but how can I add CLIENT as well ?

Comment: `select client, (case`  and `group by client, (case when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `name`.  The query can be simplified to:

```
select name,
      (case when s2.SEVERITYLEVEL in (1, 2, 3) then 'Moderate' 
            when s2.SEVERITYLEVEL in (4, 5, 6, 7) then 'Severe' 
            when s2.SEVERITYLEVEL in (8, 9, 10) then 'Severe' 
       end) as severity,
      count(*) as total 
from s2
group by name, severity
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```

Notes:

- MySQL lets you use aliases in the `group by`.  This is a big convenience.
- Give the new column name a new name.  This is just generally good advice to keep things unambiguous.
- Superfluous backticks just make the query harder to write and to read.  No harm, but why bother?
- I understand `count(1)` but `count(0)` just seems confusing, especially for less experienced people.  `count(*)` is the SQL standard construct for counting rows.

Comment: your solution is almost working.  However, from my desired output, severitylevel are not grouped together.  For same client "Bob", multiple "severe" will show up.  I want Bob (all severe grouped together) ... no duplicate severe.....thx

Comment: @enkiki . . . The `group by` has `severity` (the new column name), not `severitylevel`.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend to put your severities into separate table. That would help to avoid a lot of complexity in future and make many queries much more performant.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f25cf/3

```
SELECT client, title, sum(total)
FROM s2 
LEFT JOIN severity
ON s2.severitylevel = severity.id
GROUP BY client, title
```